# Jenkins Slave Java path on MacOS

Tags: macos, jenkins, jenkins-agent

**Here is my jenkins slave configure**
[image: configure_img]

**Here is the process result**
[image: result_img]

Is there anybody can help me to solve it?
Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post text output as image, copy the raw text next time, please.

Comment: You will also have more success if you switch your application to english, so that everybody can understand the outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration setting for the Java path (?) is incorrect (you supplied `/usr/bin`). You see it in the output that it tries to launch a command called `/usr/bin`, which is not an executable file. That's why you get permission denied for it.

An example for a correct path would be `/usr/bin/java`, or wherever your `java` executable is located.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting detailed error and configuration.

You need to fix the Java executable path in your slave configuration.

1) You can find your Java executable from below command

$ which java

2) Test if java is properly configured from terminal:

$ java -version
You should see something like

java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)